# Getting number of audio channels for an AudioTrack

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, media-source

I have a video element, with data being added via MSE.  I'm trying to determine how many audio channels there are in each track.

The AudioTrack objects themselves don't have a property with this information.  The only way I know to go about it is to use the Web Audio API:

```
const v = document.querySelector('video');
const ctx = new OfflineAudioContext(32, 48000, 48000);
console.log(Array.from(v.audioTracks).map((track) => {
  return ctx.createBufferSource(track.sourceBuffer).channelCount;
}));
```

For a video with a single mono track, I expect to get `[1]`.  For a video with a single stereo track, I expect to get `[2]`.  Yet, every time I get `[2]` no matter what the channel count is in the original source.

**Questions:**

- Is there a proper direct way to get the number of channels in an AudioTrack?
- Is there something else I could be doing with the Web Audio API to get the correct number of channels?

Comment: I think on mono both channels are the same right?

Comment: @KilianHertel Yes, but that doesn't tell me anything about the underlying channel count.  I could sample the audio and it could be mono at one moment, and be stereo the next.  Even in the case where both channels were identical the whole time, I'd still want to report that there are two channels if there are two channels.

Comment: So why don't you take the first part of each channel and compare them with each other? If they are the same they are mono if not they are stereo. For example with myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(channel); In other words there is no easy way you have to make one yourself but it is possible.

Comment: And mono runs always on two channels otherwise you wouldn't hear the music on both speakers.

Comment: As I said, I want to detect the actual channel count in the media data.  Comparing them doesn't tell me anything.  I could have two identical channels, and a comparison would tell me it's mono and yet the underlying source would actually be stereo.

Comment: What do you mean? It's always stereo in the hardware! Mono is how it got recorded the channels are always two so there is no Mono in hardware all right? The source is always stereo, because we want to hear the music on two channels => Left and Right. If channel 1 = channel 2 it is what we would describe as mono => the right speaker gives the same signal as the left speaker.

Comment: It is a hardware channel count for each speaker. 1 left 1 right = two always. if Channel count is one there would only be a signal on one speaker. Nobody would like to hear that. Imagine if you have a headphone and you hear only the right speaker if it is mono => would be weird wouldn't it?

Comment: @KilianHertel Clearly you're not understanding what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to detect what's in the original media data.  It doesn't matter what the channel mapping on the output is at all.  In fact, I might not even play this output.  And no, the source is not always stereo, nor is the hardware always stereo.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon an answer for this that seems to be working. It looks like by using [decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) we can grab some buffer data about a file. I built a little function that returns a Promise with the buffer data that should return the correct number of channels of an audio file:

```
function loadBuffer(path) {
  return fetch(path)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(
      buffer =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          audioContext.decodeAudioData(
            buffer,
            data => resolve(data),
            err => reject(err)
          )
        )
    )
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
loadBuffer(audioSource).then(data => console.log(data.numberOfChannels))
```

Might be best to store and reuse the data if it can be called multiple times.